# Scheduling WordPress auto-updates

Tags: updates, wordpress, auto-updates

Is it possible to schedule when WordPress does its automatic updates? I don't want my site going down for an update during peak times or really any time during the day. I wish there was an option in the admin panel to schedule updates like you can with Windows.

Comment: This would be on-topic at wordpress.SE; off-topic here (hover on [wordpress] tag).

Comment: Here's another starting point for you in your task: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/automatic-wordpress-updates-how-to-turn-them-on-or-off-and-decide-which-is-right-for-youYou might search around for an applicable plug-in too that'll suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a self-hosted version of WordPress, then you can use [WP Update Settings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-updates-settings/) or [Advanced Automatic Updates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-updater/). Both allow you to automatically update WordPress. The second has a lot more options and more reviews.

If you are using WordPress's hosted option, by default your WordPress will self update.